# Delay a Function Call within Coffeescript + Jquery File

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I have a Coffeescript+Jquery file within a Ruby on Rails project that I want to add a delay functionality to it I have been experimenting with setTimeout and I cant get anything to work, here is the code...

products.coffee

```
$ ->
  if $('.pagination').length && $('#products').length
    $(window).scroll ->
      url = $('.pagination .next_page').attr('href')
      if url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50
        $('.pagination').text("Loading more products...")
        $.getScript(url)
    $(window).scroll()
```

The $.getScript(url) line is what I want to delay calling for 5 seconds, I have tried placing a setTimeout function call before that line, I also tried using setTimeout($.getScript(url), 5000) and nothing worked. Since this is Coffeescript+Jquery I cant find much online about this.

I believe the setTimeout function is not delaying within the window, but rather somewhere else. Not sure tho.

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I also tried using setTimeout($.getScript(url), 5000)

That's because you're not using setTimeout correctly.

the signature is `setTimeout(FUNCTION, TIME)`

You need to pass an *actual function* there, yet you're passing `$.getScript(url)`, which is *the result of calling a function* (not a function itself).

Instead you can simply wrap your getScript call in an anonymous function:

```
setTimeout ->
  $.getScript(url)
, 5000

# or, one liner if you prefer
setTimeout (-> $.getScript(url)), 5000
```

Comment: hey, this worked, thank you for the help and your explanation. I thought setTimeout would also evaluate an expression called to it. New to jQuery so thanks for the help

Comment: This is not a jQuery thing, it's how callbacks in Javascript work. however coffeescript 2 does support [async](https://coffeescript.org/#async-functions) ... if you look at that link they give an example for this specific situation when you want to delay an action without a callback.